# Testing JSF application with JMeter - ViewState issue

Tags: java, jsf, viewstate, jmeter, load-testing

All day I try to run JMeter tests of my JSF application.
I am aware of `ViewState`, but it seemed to be quite simple issue. I prepared Regular Expression Extractor:

```
Reference Name: jsfViewState
Regular expression: id=\"javax.faces.ViewState\" value=\"(.+?)\"
Template $1$
Match No. 1
```

[image: Regular Exp Extractor]

The following samplers are created with proxy and recording.

First request `/TourJSF/pages/protected/admin/addTourPage.xhtml`. This is `GET` request from which ViewState will be extracted.

[image: First GET]

The `POST` request `/TourJSF/pages/protected/admin/addTourPage.xhtml` where .`${jsfViewStete}` is passed into `javax.faces.ViewState`

[image: jsfViewState passed]

The second `GET` request, now very important in this case.

[image: Second GET]

The results:

First `GET`. On the right we can see value of ViewState.

[image: first GET result]

`Debug Sampler` which shows that jsfViewState value is correct. We can compare it with the previous screen.

[image: Debug Sampler]

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/pages/protected/admin/addTourPage.xhtml - View /pages/protected/admin/addTourPage.xhtml could not be restored.
```

[image: ViewExpiredException addTourPage.xhtml could not be restored]

I found some blogs and topics about this issue but many of them were unsolved. If it is needed I can put links to these topics. I am really confused...

Where is the issue? Maybe something with

- `jsessionid`?
- `HTTP Header Manager` in every `HTTP Request`? I deleted `HTTP Header Manager` but nothing changed.
- something with JSF apllication? When I added context-param `com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility` into `web.xml`, there was no `ViewExpiredException` but the content of returned page was not correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aren't you missing a Cookie Manager ?

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Also read this:

- http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter

Comment: I can't believe it... HTTP Cookie Manager in Thread Group helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: I already been using the HTTP Cookie Manager but I still get the issue even though I have been passing the extracted jsf view state. However, the second link you provided helped me. The "Some notes" section mentions that the extracted view state has to be passed as "encoded". Once I set it to encoded, the jmeter tests are going through with the JSF Portlets on WebSphere Portal. Thanks a lot!!